# problem installing canvas on ubuntu,Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, canvas, lms

I'm trying  to install canvas lms , but I have faced with the  following issue. Any help. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmZfT.png)please
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
In Gemfile:
bundler (>= 2.2.17, <= 2.2.24)

Current Bundler version:
bundler (2.2.28)

Your bundle requires a different version of Bundler than the one you're running.
Install the necessary version with `gem install bundler:2.2.24` and rerun bundler using `bundle _2.2.24_ update`

I tried updating bundle but no success yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```sh
gem install bundler -v 2.2.24
bundle _2.2.24_ install
```